# .htaccess correctly redirects from HTTP to HTTPS but why does HTTP still work?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I included the following lines of code in my `htaccess` file to redirect users to the `HTTPS` version of my site.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]   
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www\.mysite\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I type  `mysite.com` or `www.mysite.com` into the address bar it works perfect and sends me to the `HTTPS` version.
However if I go to Google, search for my site and click the link from the search results it still takes me to the `HTTP` version.  I have 3 questions on this.

1) Why doesn't the browser automatically redirect once the user makes contact with the server and my `htaccess` file?

2) Shouldn't `HTTP` be turned off once `HTTPS` is turned on?

3) To completely make the switch do I need to use redirects or something similar from inside the Godaddy control panel?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]   
    RewriteRule ^ https://www\.mysite\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

With `[OR]` because now you redirect only http without www.
Clear your browser cache before testing.

Comment: Good catch I didn't even think about adding an `[OR]`.  Is there a forum somewhere that focuses on `apache` and `.htaccess`?  I'm trying to learn it but there doesn't seem to be much out there.

Comment: There are really many examples on this site. For the documentation and the examples of bases, the site of Apache is logically the reference.

Comment: I added the `[OR]` to my `.htaccess` and it worked perfect.  My site is hosted on Godaddy.  As an experiment I added the `[OR]` to the `.htaccess` of a different site hosted by Network Solutions and it threw an error "too many redirects".  So... I guess not all versions of Apache interpret `[OR]` the same way.  I removed the `[OR]` and it worked fine again on Network Solutions.

Comment: It already exists in Apache 2.0, I do not know before. Try to clear your cache.

Comment: Cache cleared and same problem.  Not sure why Network Solutions doesn't like `[OR]`.  Interestingly enough when I leave off the `[OR]` it appears to check both lines of RewriteCond.  So Godaddy needs the `[OR]` and for some reason Network Solutions only works correct without the `[OR]`.  But no problem at least I've got them both working.

Comment: The problem can be with `%{HTTPS} off` Sometimes this changes for the type of implementation of the ssl.